# Convert Postgres timestamp without timezone to PHP datetime

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, utc

I'm pulling records from a Postgres DB and then saving them to a MySQL DB.  I'm fairly new to Postgres and I'm having a difficult time with these timestamps.  How can I convert these timestamp without time zone values to a PHP datetime (Central Time)?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime) constructor takes a parameter for the timezone. If the constructor can't parse the format you're getting from Postgres, the DateTime class also has a static factory method, [DateTime::createFromFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), in which you can specify the format string as the first parameter.